# How to swipe button to the left in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

An element can be flicked to the left, after that the button will appear with which you can remove an element from the list. I have a vertical layout ("Content"). I can add multiple children in that element - Item. The content itself is dragging with all of its children. Is any tips how i can make that?

[image: Structure of scene]
[image: Item element]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about it is on your button class, implement the `IDragXXX` interfaces Unity provides (`IBeginDragHandler`, `IDragHandler` & `IEndDragHandler`). It will automatically send you drag events back to the callback and you can add the desired effect.